Screenshot of the Week #127: Halloween!
This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 127th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! GammaGames's screenshot from the-longest-road-on-earth won with 18 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until October 28, 2024, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at November 4, 2024, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Theme - Halloween!
It's the spooky season, and so per usual, this contest's theme is Halloween! Share your spookiest screenshots so that we all feel the need to keep the lights on tonight while we sleep.
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

I'm surprised we don't use the fun tag for this.

@Daemons Because this is serious business.

@Joachim I can’t tell if you’re joking or not…

@Daemons because it's a competition, after all, and we ain't no de Coubertin.

@pinckerman I’m… pretty sure that was a joke. I have no idea what it references though.

Yeah I'm joking, too (maybe), I think that fun is just a bad tag, nobody used it in the last 5 years

@pinckerman didn't even know it existed :)

@pinckerman You mean this user used it in the past 5 years?


“What is a man? [tosses goblet, which breaks] A miserable little pile of secrets.
But enough talk, HAVE AT YOU!”
  - Dracula, dead-cells

Anyone know how to make the quote attribution (- Dracula [...]) indent 4 spaces or so? Hitting space or tab doesn't work.

To indent, you could use an &emsp; or two.  P.S. It’s usually easier to leave a double space at the end of a line, rather than using <br>.

I understood that reference.

"Die monster, you don't belong in this world!"

@galacticninja We commend you for your knowledge.

Small nit-picking: it's not a goblet. It looks more like a wine glass. But I don't drink alcohol myself so I cannot say for sure

@Clockwork This quote appears in Dead Cells, but it originates in an old Castlevania game called Symphony of the Night, where I believe a goblet was used. It’s just a reference to that game in this game.

Yeah, I played Symphony of the night, and I remember the sound of breaking glass when he throws it https://youtu.be/5tV33Ewf_hw?t=35

Ah, my bad, I wasn't aware of the vocabulary. I just learned goblet (which can made of glass) are similar but have a wider opening than wine glass.


Troll in the dungeon!
hp-sorcerers-stone / game-boy-advance

Yer a wizard, Harry

This IS Halloween!

kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

Welp. Time to replay the entire KH series for the 10th time

@Wondercricket I've been having these weird thoughts lately...

@Clockwork Like, is any of this for real or not?

@Wondercricket None if this... makes sense to me.

A pair of curious foglets in the-witcher-3:


An orthodontist’s nightmare.

Something tells me that Necromorph is not dead.

dead-space

Apparently, EA renamed Dead Space 1 into Dead Space (2008) in Steam, in order to differentiate it from the remake.



The Feeder Zombie’s thought process is quite simple: eat brains… eat brains… eat brains….
Although, to be fair, the stains on their T-shirts are mostly melon juice.

timesplitters-2

The flavour text you added has quote formatting. What's the quote from?

@Daemons In TS2, if you go to Options / Player Options / View Gallery you can see all the characters you’ve unlocked, and you also get a bit of flavour text.

It’s always cool when the game gives you info in weird and funny ways.

@Daemons It’s the only explanation for the dozen or so watermelons found throughout that level.

Watermelons? No, they're clearly heads painted in alternating shades of green.
